# Weird date and time format (01 00:00:47), how do I separate them for the whole google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

With a format like this 01 00:00:47, how do I separate the date from the time in excel for the whole data set?

Comment: what the format stands for? 01 like 2001 or 01 like january/day ? share a copy/sample of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: 01 on the left is the day, this data set has 16,000 entries which occur over a 31 day period. Actual month and year are not defined. Thank you for any and all help

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(SPLIT(A1:A; " ")))
```

Comment: I get a REF errror with this one

Comment: @TannerJohnson can you share a copy of your sheet?